# Passportjs security token security

Tags: authentication

I am using [Express js](https://expressjs.com/) web framework and [Passport js](http://passportjs.org/) library for authentication. Everything is working fine but I have a doubt.

To maintain a persistent login session passport js uses [cookie session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) and it saves two cookies inside user's browser. One is `session` and another is `session.sig`. I am also having authorization module in my app which comes after passing the authentication.

My problem is when two users are logged in and both are having different roles (rights and permissions). If one of the users is copying the `session` and `session.sig` value from another user's browser and pasting inside own browser's cookie then he is able to get his account details and rights.

So it is a vulnerability or it is a general thing?

What if someone uses a web-proxy tool like "Burp"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Session tokens are considered secret, if you copy them from one browser to another then it's normal that you can actually access it as your applications looks at these values to verify identity.

If you are using a web-proxy tool like burp, attackers have already succesfully performed a man-in-the-middle. That's why we use SSL/TLS: to encrypt the traffic so that this sensitive token doesn't leak.

There are some mitigating actions you could take such as checking the user agent or the IP addresses for each session. If these change then you immediately invalidate the session.

Answer (score 1):

Different AppSec professionals take different views on this. I've known some who have argued that this is a vulnerability.

Personally, I think: "it depends" (I know, that phrase is cliched).

Two reasons:

1. If an authenticated user is cooperating with an attacker - or is an attacker by themselves, then you must accept that the application & data are exposed to the extent that the user has access. I treat this as "hey this is pretty much the same as the user passing on his login credentials" - even though technically it is different.
2. The same applies if the client system / browser is compromised to the extent that an attacker has access to everything on it.

However, moving session cookies from one browser to another or worse, one system to another is defensible to some extent - through the use of per-conversation nonce and/or maintaining other client-profile-info such as UA Strings and IP addresses. There are limits on how far you can go with this line of defense, but then no single defense is enough against a determined attacker.